# Caught exception while loading: Character [-]

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

today I made update of ROS (Ubuntu 11.04, ROS Electric from deb repo), run "roslaunch cob_bringup sim.launch" and then "rosrun rviz rviz", which gave me this error:

```
[ERROR] [1317112938.826534360, 19.093000000]: Caught exception while loading: Character [-] at element [4] is not valid in Graph Resource Name [cob3-3].  Valid characters are a-z, A-Z, 0-9, / and _.
```

Before update if worked fine. I'm using git version of cob_simulation stack (with env. variables ROBOT=cob3-2, ROBOT_ENV=ipa-kitchen, SIMX=-r).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11321/caught-exception-while-loading:-character-%5B-%5D/) by [ZdenekM](https://answers.ros.org/users/1081/zdenekm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 704 on 2011-09-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I expect that some of the launch files are using the ROBOT environment variable in the node names to avoid name collisions.

A dash '-' is not a valid name for a node.  This has always been the policy.  I believe that in Electric the parser is now stricter about enforcing it.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-12-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1